# Changing the text of button without changing CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am tinkering around with HTML and Javascript and have encountered a problem.

I have a button which animates on hover and changes text and color on click. 
When clicked again it goes back to the same color and text as before. This I am handling with a JS file.

My problem is that on clicking and hovering for the first time everything works fine but after first click, the animations are gone forever and the button now only changes color and text, no hover animation is there.

HTML for the button:

```
    <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" id="buttonclick" onclick="setColor()">
<span>Enable Control</span></button>
```

See this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2tovyz6/) for full explanation.

Comment: Because when you set the `innerHTML` you are removing the span which the transition applies to. You start with `<button><span></span></button>` but you end up with `<button></button>`.

Comment: You need to set the innerHTML of the span inside the button not the button itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation it's a bit vague and the title is a bit confusing. I suppose you want the same hover you had at the beggining (when you press the button and goes back to blue then the hover has to appear again). I will fix it:

The problem is that you are avoiding the span tag on your code line:

```
property.innerHTML = "Enable control"
```

You should change it to:

```
property.innerHTML = "<span>Enable control</span>"
```

The same goes in the else part:

```
 property.innerHTML = "<span>Disable control</span>"
```

Replace your Javascript code with this one fixed:

```
var count = 1;

function setColor() {
  var property = document.getElementById('buttonclick');
  if (count == 0) {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "#4f8ff7"
    property.innerHTML = "<span>Enable control</span>"
    alert("Disabled");
    count = 1;
  } else {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "#a84237"
    property.innerHTML = "<span>Disable control</span>"
    alert("Enabled");
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! careless mistake on my part :(

Comment: Also in your code 
property.innerHTML = "</span>Disable control</span>"  

should be 

property.innerHTML = "<span>Disable control</span>"

Comment: @Ravikishan No problem bro! And you are right. I have updated my answer if that's was the solution you were looking for please click the answer as correct or right that way it will be helpfull to other users too.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `innerHtml` of the button. That replaces your span element with text.

Check your updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2tovyz6/1/).